# Composer Server won't load vendor file into server root

Tags: php, terminal, composer-php, mamp-pro

I started looking into using `composer` for my `php` project. i have MAMP Pro and would like to continue to use that for my development hosting. The problem is that I can't get composer to run anywhere accept in my `/Users/***/` folder (where it runs really well). How would I get it to run in the root of my MAMP Server? I have messed with the `.bash_profile` file adding the following lines:

```
alias composer='php composer.phar'
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.10/bin:$PATH
```

That does not work (and neither does the alias). The `vendor` file still shows up in the `/Users/***/` folder.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You appear to be missing a quote (`'`) after the `composer.phar` part, is this a typo when you typed the question, or like this in the actual file?

Comment: Typo in the question

Comment: Edited it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after looking at it a little bit more here's what I figured out using @Lokesh Gamot's answer and the composer site. Again, this is geared to use with MAMP.

1. Find the path of your development server. I would suggest putting `var_dump(getcwd());` at the top of your index.php file to get the path to show up on your index page. For me, it was `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.../web-root`
2. Because I wanted composer in my server root, I inputted `cd "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/"` into the terminal.
3. I then downloaded the file using `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --filename=composer`. This installs Composer into `"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/"` as a file named `composer`.

When I begin a new project, I have to move the `composer` file into the project root using `mv composer "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/*Destination Root*"` and then navigate the terminal to that same root by using: `cd "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/*Destination Root*"`. What I was missing was needing to move the `composer` file around to each root when I needed it.

After that, I can use composer using `php composer`. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do a global installation:

Since Composer works with the current working directory it is possible to install it in a system wide way.

1.Change into a directory in your path like cd /usr/local/bin

2.Get Composer curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

3.Make the phar executable chmod a+x composer.phar

4.Change into a project directory cd /path/to/my/project

5.Use Composer as you normally would composer.phar install

Update: Sometimes you can't or don't want to download at /usr/local/bin (some have experienced user permissions issues or restricted access), in this case you can try this

```
Open terminal
curl -sS http://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --filename=composer
chmod a+x composer
sudo mv composer /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Comment: Does this method download the files into the server root?

Comment: yeah, i think it will run there.

Comment: Ok. So here's what I did... do you see any issues with this?

`cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs`

`curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --filename=composer
`
This installed the composer file into htdocs which has all my server roots. Theoretically, the vendor file should be accessible to all the following roots... right?

Comment: After that, it won't work if I change directories to my project root and use it, even though there's a composer.json and composer.lock in there